# How to loopthrough a table without cursor- oracle sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to loop through a table and insert one of the column value to another table. How can I perform this without a cursor.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Status (Id, StatusCode, Description) AS
SELECT 11, 'CO', 'Completed' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 22, 'CA', 'Carried' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 33, 'AA', 'Carried' FROM DUAL;
```

And another table Table2

```
CREATE TABLE MainTable (Id, StatusTableId, MainTableData)
```

In the `Maintable`, I need to get three rows of data:

| id | statustableid | ReservationId | maintabledata |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 1 | ancsd |
| 2 | 22 | 1 | dadsa |
| 3 | 33 | 1 | adasd |

Here I want to loop through the `status` table and insert `id`  (here 11,22,33) into new table. Can I do this without a cursor?

Comment: Let's see, you have the tables Status, Table2, MainTable and finally new table?

Comment: Where do you find the values ancsd, dadsa and adasd?

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that you have created your tables and inserted the known data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Status (Id, StatusCode, Description) AS
SELECT 11, 'CO', 'Completed' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 22, 'CA', 'Carried' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 33, 'AA', 'Carried' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE MainTable (Id NUMBER, StatusTableId NUMBER, MainTableData VARCHAR2(10));

INSERT INTO maintable (id, maintabledata)
  SELECT 1, 'ancsd' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'dadsa' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'adasd' FROM DUAL;
```

Then you want to reference the `id` in `status` for each row in `maintable`; however, there is nothing in common between the two tables so you have to generate your own way of correlating between the tables.

The first thing **YOU** need to do it to work out how the two tables are linked (why does the row in `maintable` with an `id` of `1` want to have a status of `11`?) and then, when you understand the reason why that `id` should have that `statusid` then **YOU** can implement that logic to update the value. However, since the logic is not obvious then we can only provide possible guesses that give the expected output (but maybe only coincidentally).

For example, you could number the rows in `Status` according to the order of the `id` column and then correlate that to the `id` column of `maintable` and use a `MERGE` statement to update the table:

```
MERGE INTO maintable m
USING (
  SELECT id,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rn
  FROM   status
) s
ON (m.id = s.rn)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET statustableid = s.id;
```

Then `maintable` contains:

| ID | STATUSTABLEID | MAINTABLEDATA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | ancsd |
| 2 | 22 | dadsa |
| 3 | 33 | adasd |

There are many other ways you could look to correlate the two tables; such as on `mainTable.Id` and the first character of `Status.Id`:

```sql
MERGE INTO maintable m
USING status s
ON (m.id = SUBSTR(s.id, 1, 1))
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET statustableid = s.id;
```

However, to answer your question:

> Can I do this without a cursor?

Yes, as demonstrated above, you can.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wxNRTTvg)

Comment: there is no relation between these two tables..i have added a new colum reservationid to make it clear..so for the same reservation id (1 in this example) i need there status. so just loop through the first table and insert that many rows in to new table with the id...

Comment: @sooryakumar There is still no relationship between `maintable` and `status` table so it is unclear how a `reservationid` column would help.

Comment: i have added it to show for a reservation id there will be 3 entries in the new table with those status( it is actually a channel)..so for a particular reservation there is 3 channels